# Create function that loops through columns in a Data frame

Tags: python, list, dataframe, function, jupyter-notebook

I am a new coder using jupyter notebook. I have a dataframe that contains 23 columns with different amounts of values( at most 23 and at least 2) I have created a function that normalizes the contents of one column below.

```
def normalize(column):
    y = DFref[column].values[()]
    y = x.astype(int)
    KGF= list()
    for element in y:
        element_norm = element / x.sum()
        KGF.append(element_norm) 
    return KGF
```

I am now trying to create a function that loops through all columns in the Data frame. Right now if I plug in the name of one column, it works as intended. What would I need to do in order to create a function that loops through each column and normalizes the values of each column, and then adds it to a new dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear if all 23 columns are numeric, but I will assume they are. Then there are a number of ways to solve this. The method below probably isn't the best, but it might be a quick fix for you...

```
colnames = DFref.columns.tolist()
normalised_data = {}

for colname in colnames:
    normalised_data[colname] = normalize(colname)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(normalised_data)
```

Comment: Hello Adrian and Dharman, thank you for the help. Yes it is numeric and  your code worked nicely. I am a beginner to this stuff, so thanks for your help.